# Is it possible to send data from a JavaScript browser app to a local python server directly?

Tags: javascript, python

As the question suggests I'm trying to find a way using JavaScript to send some data to a local python server. I know that using javascript. I know that browser JS can't import any libraries via "Require". Does anyone know of a method using JS on its own?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Make your [Python app listen for HTTP requests](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/), and then use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) from JavaScript.

Comment: This should work. Flask would be the best bet for a quick and easy local server